# Manipulate table in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5

I am consuming api successfully in knockout.js.But according to my table definition(id,name,debit,credit,amount),this is based on accounting.The amount i want to show if it is credit or debit since not all the amount are under the debit and credit the same time.kindly help me to diplay the amount under redit and debit respectively.
This is the viewmodel

```
 function JournalViewModel() {
var self = this;
self.Period = ko.observable();
self.PayGroup = ko.observable();
self.PayGroups = ko.observableArray([]);



self.LoadPeriods = function () {

    $.ajax({

        url: baseUrl + 'api/Process/Load',
        type: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.Successfull == 1) {
                self.Period(data.Model.CurrentPeriod);
                self.PayGroups(data.Model.Paygroups);
            }

        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}

self.periodId = ko.observable();
self.PaygroupId = ko.observable();
self.Journal = ko.observableArray([]);
self.PayMaster = ko.observableArray();

self.LoadJournal = function () {

    $.ajax({

        url: baseUrl + 'api/Journal/LoadJournal/'+periodId +'/'+self.PaygroupId(),
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {              
            if (data.HasError == 0) {
                self.Journal(data.Model);
                console.log(data.Model);
                alert("Journal Successfully Processed");
                $("#listTable").DataTable();

            }

        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}

self.StartDate = ko.observable()
self.EndDate = ko.observable()
self.NbDays = ko.observable();
self.NbHours = ko.observable();
self.Code = ko.observable();
self.CountEmployees = ko.observable();
self.LoadPeriods();
}ko.applyBindings(new JournalViewModel());
```

this is my view

```
  @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
  <nav role="navigation" aria-labelledby="system-breadcrumb">
 <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#">Process</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Journals</a></li>
 </ol>
 </nav>
  <div class="box box-primary">
  <div class="box-body">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-2">
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="PeriodTxt">Pay Group</label>
                <select data-bind="options: PayGroups,
                    optionsText: 'Name',
                    optionsValue: 'Id',
                    optionsCaption: 'Choose...',
                    value:PaygroupId" class="form-control"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="PeriodTxt">Period</label>
                <input id="FullNameTxt" class="form-control" type="text" 
   readonly="readonly"
                       data-bind="value:Period()?Period().Code:''" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="StatusTxt">Number of Hours</label>
                <input id="StatusTxt" class="form-control" type="text" 
 readonly="readonly"
                       data-bind="value:Period()?Period().NbHours:''" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ds"></label>
                <input type="submit" value="Load Journal" data-
  bind="click:LoadJournal" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>
  <div class="well">
   <div class="well-body">
    <table id="listTable" class='table table-striped table-bordered'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Account Code
                </th>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Debit
                </th>
                <th>
                    Credit
                </th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach:Journal">             
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text:AcctId">                            
                    </td>
                    <td data-bind="text:AcctDescription">                           
                    </td>
                    <!-- ko if:Debit==1 -->
                    <td data-bind="text:Amount">                        
                    </td>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- ko if:Credit==1 -->
                    <td data-bind="text:Amount"></td>
                    <!-- /ko -->                                                                
 </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
 </div>
 @section Scripts{
 <script>periodId = '@ViewBag.PeriodId';</script>
 }
```

Comment: If you add this in a JFiddle we can help you better

Comment: @LiefdeWen: Not an off-site fiddle, an **on-site** Stack Snippet (the `[<>]` toolbar button; lytakyn, [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, and whether you've already made an attempt you need help fixing, or what...

Comment: Yes i need help to fix it,the if condition in knockout.js should be able to solve it,i'm not writing it well,i need help to put the amount under the specific credit and debit assigned to the name

Comment: The Debit and Credit properties, are they defined in your datamodel? You're showing the same thing in both cases, so why have a condition in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have the if condition on the  tag, which will not render if false. The trick is to put it inside the  tag as you want that to be shown all the time, just not the value inside. (If I understood your question correctly ofcourse)

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Account Code</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Debit</th>
      <th>Credit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text:AcctId"></td>
      <td data-bind="text:AcctDescription"></td>
      <td>
        <span data-bind="if: Debit == 1">
          <!-- ko text: Amount -->
          <!-- /ko -->
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span data-bind="if: Credit == 1">
          <!-- ko text: Amount -->
          <!-- /ko -->
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```